# how to implement file filter in java

Tags: java

How do I implement a file filter in Java so I can limit the possible files that are shown to a user in a "select file" dialog, or limit the list of files that I see when listing the files in a directory?

Comment: Did you check this? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/filechooser/FileFilter.html

Comment: SO vs. Google: 1) must type more; 2) glacially slow response; 3) caustic remarks from people pissed off at you soliciting their effort to forward your question to google and copy-paste what they found.

Answer (score 0):

After Googling for 'java file filter', this result comes up first:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html#filters

That documentation should tell you all you need to know.